# CouchDB and querying not by document ID

Tags: rest, couchdb

Is my understanding correct, that querying documents in CouchDB can only be done in a RESTful way by document ID but not by attributes (e.g. something like .../person?firstname=john).

For every query not by document ID I need a view (which means making a map function)?

Greetings Kudi

Comment: Yes, by `id` or a view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CouchDb does not support ad-hoc queries, but instead you define views by defining a map function. You are in full control of what data the map should produce: Id, Key, Value. You then can query this in a range of ways using key, keys, keyrange etc.

http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/views.html

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs.html#view-functions